# Faded image edges on canvas using getImageData

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvas, getimagedata

Using getImageData, I'm trying to create a radial fade effect on an image where point(0,0) has an alpha of 0 and point(img.width, img.height) has an alpha of 0.5 sort of like this:

[image: radial fade]
(The last point has an alpha of 1.0, but imagine it's 0.5.)

I've been able to create a linear alpha increase in my `for` loop using

```
    imgData.data[i+3]=i/imgData.length;
```

but the left edge (obviously) becomes more defined as the loop iterates.

I've tried using two loops, one to create row "breaks" in the array, and the other to handle the alpha manipulation like so:

```
    for(var j=0;j<imgData.height;j++){
        for(var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4){
            imgData.data[i+3] = 0 + 125 * i/imgData.data.length;
            }
    }
```

but the performance of this is really slow and it doesn't achieve the fade that I'm looking for. I'm also not sure I'm doing that properly. I also tried [Faster Canvas Pixel Manipulation with Typed Arrays](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/) as outlined on the Mozilla Hacks site, but the image wasn't even drawn to the canvas using that method. (I'm using Chrome - not sure if that's the issue or if it's my code.)

Any ideas?

EDIT: Thanks to markE for the great solution - it's beautifully quick. I mentioned this in my comment to him, but here's the full code for creating a greyscale image (part of my requirements) that has the fade pictured in mark's demo.

```
    img_width = window.innerWidth/2.5;
    img_height = img_width * (9/16);

    //hidden_ctx is hidden behind a background layer                    
    var g1=hidden_ctx.createRadialGradient(500,500,550,500,500,650);
    g1.addColorStop(0.00,"rgba(0,0,0,0.7)");
    g1.addColorStop(0.30,"rgba(0,0,0,0.35)");
    g1.addColorStop(1.00,"rgba(0,0,0,0.00)");

    hidden_ctx.fillStyle=g1;
    hidden_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, img_width, img_height);

    hidden_ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-in";

    //custom drawImage method where selected[num] contains
    //contains images & metadata
    drawIt(hidden_ctx, selected[num].image[0], 0, 0, img_width, img_height);

    imgData=hidden_ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img_width, img_height);

    // invert colors
    for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4)
        {
           grayscaled = 0.34 * imgData.data[i] + 0.5 * imgData.data[i + 1] + 0.16 * imgData.data[i + 2];
           imgData.data[i]=grayscaled;
           imgData.data[i+1]=grayscaled;
           imgData.data[i+2]=grayscaled;

        }

    //places the converted image in the lower right corner where 
    //WIDTH/HEIGHT is window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, WIDTH-img_width, HEIGHT-img_height);
```

Comment: you should simply draw a gradient over the bitmap using values like rgba(255,255,255,0.5). ed: oops, just noticed the bg alpha problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use compositing to achieve a fade effect more efficiently.

- draw a radial gradient that fades to transparent in the top-left corner.
- Adjust the radial gradient to meet your design needs.
- set compositing to `source-in` which causes any subsequent draws to only appear over existing non-transparent pixels.
- draw your image (the image will fade the same way your radial gradient did)

Using compositing is especially efficient if the device has a GPU because compositing will use it.

[image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/thqamsLk/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    canvas{ background-color: lightgray; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/reef.jpg";
    function start(){

        canvas.width=img.width;
        canvas.height=img.height;

        var g1=ctx.createRadialGradient(500,500,550,500,500,650);
        g1.addColorStop(0.00,"rgba(0,0,0,1.00)");
        g1.addColorStop(0.30,"rgba(0,0,0,0.75)");
        g1.addColorStop(1.00,"rgba(0,0,0,0.00)");

        ctx.fillStyle=g1;
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);

        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-in";

        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Fading an image using compositing</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I didn't know you could do this. Thank you so much.
I didn't include this in my post but I also had to convert it to grayscale, so I still needed to utilize the getImageData. For anyone that's interested - I drew the image on my hidden context using the composite to create the fade, then used getImageData for that area, converted the pixels to grayscale, and drew it back with putImageData